# Zypper: How to list installed packages that are not in a repo

Tags: zypper

In a system using Zypper for package management (openSuse, in my case) how can one get a list of all installed packages that are not associated with a currently enabled repository?

Real problem:
When upgrading distributions (e.g., from openSuse 12.1 to 12.2), I disable all non-standard repositories that I've enabled.  Often, I only added them to get a new version of a particular tool, but that newer version is included by default in the updated distribution.  Sometimes though, additional packages were installed from the repository, but I don't know how to detect those.  The system works, but those packages will never be updated since I removed the providing repository after the upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit about messing around with zypper inquiries.

1) Find installed packages, which come from non-opensuse-distribution-repositories:

```
zypper search -s | grep "i |" | grep -vi "| patch" | grep -vi "| opensuse" > list1.txt
```

2) Find packages, which are available from opensuse repositories (no matter whether they are installed or not):

```
zypper search -s | grep "v |" | grep -vi "| patch" | grep -i "| opensuse" > list2.txt
```

3) Identify packages from list1, which are not represented in list2:

```
cat list1.txt | cut -d " " -f3 | cut -d " " -f1 | while read line
do
    if [ "$(cat list2.txt | grep -i $line)" = "" ]; then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

This should kind of solve the case (tested on openSUSE 11.3).

Answer (score 3):

The option `pa` is probably more appropriate:

```
zypper pa -i
```

lists all the installed packages and their available versions and repositories. You can choose to list only the packages belonging to a certain repository with the `-r` flag:

```
zypper pa -i -r openSUSE-12.1
```

from there on you can use the strategies proposed by @ernestopheles to find the ones matching your needs.

Comment: I've started using `zypper pa -i | grep @System`; I used to use `zypper search -i -s -t package | grep "| (System Packages)\s*$"`

Answer (score 2):

In more recent versions of openSUSE you can use

```
zypper pa --orphaned
```

to list those packages.